# Get KERN_DEBUG messages into syslog on rhel7/centos7?

Tags: centos, rhel, kernel-modules, rsyslog

I've been trying to get KERN_DEBUG messages logged to a file in centos7, but have had no luck. I can get them just fine from "dmesg," but not /var/log/messages or /var/log/dmesg

Here's a MWE kernel module that I can use to test:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

int init_module(void) {
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void) {
}
```

And corresponding Makefile:

```
obj-m += hello.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I tried adding another log file by modifying the rsyslog configuration:

```
[root@centos7 ]# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/kern.conf 
kern.*      /var/log/kern.log
```

But even after restarting rsyslogd, it wouldn't populate. I have SELinux set to enforcing, so just for kicks I touched that file and copied the context from /var/log/messages:

```
[root@centos7 mwe]# ls -lZ /var/log/kern.log 
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0   /var/log/kern.log
```

Of course I never had any SELinux errors, that's just more of a knee-jerk reaction from running in enforcing

Has anyone configured this successfully?

Answer (score 2):

Centos 7 uses journald for syslog, rsyslog essentially gets bypassed.

If you want to use rsyslog instead, see: https://www.internetstaff.com/replace-journald-fedora-centos-redhat/

Comment: welcome to U&L, while link are acceptable as a source, can you copy/paste revelent information ?

Comment: No, I cannot, sorry. Formatting would take a bunch of my time and the linked document is well formatted and terse enough. Feel free not to upvote nor select my answer as the correct one because of this "policy", I just hope that it helps someone trying to alleviate systemd-induced pains.